# Advantages of Unity plugins over the script in Unity Plugin while getting the rendered frames from unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, plugins, render

Suppose I am using a Unity Native Plugin for getting the rendered texture by the camera and I have added the same functionality inside my project. Is there any performance difference between these two?

For 2nd one, I just added

```
    RenderTexture currentRT = RenderTexture.active;
    RenderTexture.active = cam.targetTexture;
    cam.Render();
    Texture2D image = new Texture2D(cam.targetTexture.width, cam.targetTexture.height);
    image.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, cam.targetTexture.width, cam.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);
    image.Apply();
    RenderTexture.active = currentRT;
    return image;
```

and for the 1st one, I have a native plugin something like this (https://answers.unity.com/questions/1335556/problem-with-camera-rendering.html?childToView=1488524#answer-1488524) then I am importing the plugin .dll and calling the function from the code. (N.B. GL.IssuePluginEvent could be called by the OnPostRender function of a "camera" script)

In general what I observed the 2nd approach makes my game slow while capturing the frames online but is there any advantage of using plugin in this case?

Answer (score 0):

That non-async `ReadPixels()` call is causing your frame-rate drop by invoking a GPU>CPU memory transfer and stalling the hardware pipeline.

> Are there any advantages of using a plugin in this case?

If you're using Unity 2017 or below then a plug-in is the only way to transfer GPU data asynchronously. You can find an open source plug-in here [GitHub/AsyncTextureReader](https://github.com/SlightlyMad/AsyncTextureReader).

If you're using Unity 2018 (beta) or above, you can avoid plug-ins altogether with the new *experimental* `AsyncGPUReadback` class. See here [AsyncGPUReadback](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Experimental.Rendering.AsyncGPUReadback.html).